# ASP.NET Map API with Weather Overlay?

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, bing-maps, weather

We use Google Maps API and they had a weather layer which they "sunsetted."  So it's no longer available - how can I add weather to Google Maps or is there another map API we can use in our asp.net site that shows KML data for routing information and also weather?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For Bing Maps, many developers have used various weather API's to bring this data in. Here are a few worth looking into:

https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/05/13/displaying-weather-and-traffic-conditions-in-bing-maps/

http://nowcoast.noaa.gov/help/mapservices.shtml?name=mapservices

http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/

http://datamarket.azure.com/browse/data?category=weather